# how can i create excel file with only python standard library

Tags: python, excel

I want to create Excel file in python. But when search (openPyxl, xlsxwriter) only see and that's need to install. Have another ways to create excel file like a csv?

I know that's simple question I just want to know why cannot create or I want to try if another way having..
Thanks for help...

Comment: You sure can since Excel uses a version of `xml` file format. It won't be easy though. Check format specs and parsing information here: https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000398.shtml or here: https://www.example-code.com/csharp/parse_xls.asp

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41550060/how-to-create-a-excel-file-only-with-python-standard-library

Comment: Understand that you will be replicating the work that went into creating library modules like `xlswriter`. That project is more ambitious than you seem to imagine. But as a start, try downloading one of them and see how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

Writing csv-files would be a lot easier, as they are just comma-separated and line break is just a line break. So just looping through the data with for loop and writing into the file. Xlsx-files contain a lot of other information such as metadata etc., which would make it more difficult to write without any libraries (see e.g. [the source of openpyxl](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl)).

```
with open('demo.csv', 'a') as file:
for i in range(0, 5):
    for j in range(0, 5):
        file.write(f'{i * j};')
    file.write('\n')
```

Semicolumn is due to excel csv having it as a delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I already create csv file now i want to add excel file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only the standard library to create a CSV-file you can take a look at [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Some example code from [the site](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) is:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

Comment: Thanks for answer . I already create csv file. now i want to create excel file